# Как сделать цикл в Perl?

Tags: perl, asyncio

Как сделать чтобы через каждых 100 строчек цикл засыпал, а в указаное время закрывал/открывал лог?

```
open(LOGFILE, $logfile) or die "error";
for(;;) {
  if($logfile=<LOGFILE>){
    //..........условие............
  }
}
```

Comment: Непонятно сформулирован вопрос. Прочитать скриптом 100 строчек из файла - и потом подробнее, что еще нужно сделать?

Comment: Есть лог файл прокси сервера, куда все время добавляются записи. Цикл (бесконечный) парсет лог, но при этом дает большую нагрузку на процессор. Надо чтобы через каждых 100 или больше записей он "засипал", а каждое утро после очистки лога закрывал его и заново открывал

Comment: Неправильный подход. Лучше сконфигурировать syslog, чтобы он кормил записями perl-скрипт. Другой вариант: использовать Ваш perl-скрипт как **prerotate** в конфигурационном файле logrotate

Comment: Ротация лога происходит, только другим путем. Скрипт должен только парсить.

Answer (score 1):

Тут можно использовать модуль для асинхронного чтения файла вроде [IO::Async::FileStream](http://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async::FileStream), который позволяет считывать данные, добавляемые в файл:

> This subclass of IO::Async::Stream allows reading the end of a regular file which is being appended to by some other process. It invokes the on_read event when more data has been added to the file.

В документации есть пример как раз реализующий решение описанной задачи.

Answer (score -1):

```
use File::Tail;

while (1){

    my $file = File::Tail->new(
        name        => $logfile, 
        interval    => 1,
        maxinterval => 10, 
        adjustafter => 2,
        maxbuf      => 10 * 1024 * 1024
    );

    my $counter = 0;
    while (defined my $line = $file->read ){
        if ( ++$counter == 100 ){
            sleep 1;
            $counter = 0;
        }

        last  if $counter == 0 && _is_time_to_close_handler();


        ...
    }

    $file->DESTROY(); # это необязательно
}
```